# Convergence of a sequence with dependence

Tags: probability-theory, limits, convergence-divergence, random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I want to derive a LLN for conditionally independent random variables.

Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of random variables taking values on a finite subset $B$. Assume that their conditional probability is bounded above and below by numbers that are independent on the conditioning event.

Show convergence of $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$.

Comment: How does one define the distance between a number an interval?  I'm guessing $d(x,[a,b]) = 0$ if $x \in [a,b]$, otherwise $d(x,[a,b]) = \min(|a-x|,|b-x|)$?

Comment: @TEX In my proof I don't have an event called $E_n(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-1})$. You're probably correct that it's possible to re-write my proof in terms of these events that you've defined, but currently your Steps 3-5 don't make sense as I don't know what sequence $(\alpha_n)_{n \geq 1}$ you're working with. I suspect that the issue comes down to you being a bit confused by my notations.

Comment: @TEX I don't have time right now to write out full clarifications of my proof; I suggest that you go to a probability professor at your university to work through my proof with you in person - that will probably be much, much more beneficial for you than trying to clarify everything with me over MSE.

Comment: @TEX As I think about it more, I should really at least say something explicit about why my events $E_n$ are mutually independent; I'll try to get round to doing that in the near future.

Comment: @TEX Okay, I've added a more detailed explanation now; I increasingly appreciate that my original proof was perhaps a bit too condensed. (By the way, I won't be notified that you've replied to me unless you put "@JulianNewman" at the start of the comment.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Condition (1) is the only condition needed for your desired result to hold**, as it already contains a notion of "approximately i.i.d.".

[Also, I don't understand your condition (2a): if $B$ is a finite set of real numbers, then how could a $B$-valued random variable fail to have finite first and second moments?]

---

*Proof.* I will show that
$$ P\bigg(\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{[X_k = b]} \geq \nu_l(b) \bigg)=1; $$
a similar argument will show that
$$ P\bigg(\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n 1_{[X_k = b]} \leq \nu_u(b) \bigg)=1. $$

Fix $b \in B$. If $\nu_l(b)=0$ then the desired result is trivial, so assume that $\nu_l(b) > 0$.

The strategy is to show that the desired result follows from the classical strong law of large numbers, by constructing a sequence of events $E_n$ to which classical LLN can be applied [that is to say, $(1_{E_n})_{n \geq 1}$ is an i.i.d. sequence of random variables], where $E_n \subset \{X_n=b\}$ for every $n$, and $P(E_n)=\nu_l(b)$.

Let $(U_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be an i.i.d. sequence of random variables uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$ that is independent of $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$. [We can assume without loss of generality that the underlying probability space is rich enough to admit this.] Define a sequence of events $(E_n)_{n \geq 1}$ recursively as follows:

- let $p_1=P(X_1=b)$ and let $E_1 = \left\{ X_1=b \ \text{ and } \ U_1 \leq \frac{\nu_l(b)}{p_1} \right\}$;
- for $n \geq 2$, define $p_n \colon \{0,1\}^{n-1} \to [0,1]$ such that
  $$ p_n(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-1}) = P(X_n = b | 1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1 ) $$
  for any $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-1})$ with $P(1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1) > 0$, and let
  $$ E_n = \left\{ X_n=b \ \text{ and } \ U_np_n(1_{E_1},\ldots,1_{E_{n-1}}) \leq \nu_l(b) \right\}. $$

Obviously, by construction, $E_n \subset \{X_n=b\}$ for all $n$. It remains to show that the events $E_n$ are mutually independent with $P(E_n)=\nu_l(b)$ for all $n$.

Since $\nu_l(b) \leq P(X_1=b) = p_1$ and $U_1$ is independent of $X_1$, we have
$$ P(E_1) = P(X_1=b)P\big(U_1 \leq \tfrac{\nu_l(b)}{p_1}\big) = p_1 \tfrac{\nu_l(b)}{p_1} = \nu_l(b).  $$
Now given any $n \geq 2$, since $(U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1})$ is independent of $(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})$ we have
$$ P(X_n=b | X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1}) = P(X_n=b | X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1}) \geq \nu_l(b), $$
and hence, since (by construction) $E_1,\ldots,E_{n-1} \in \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1})$, we have that for every $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-1}) \in \{0,1\}^{n-1}$ with $P(1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1) > 0$,
$$ P(X_n = b | 1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1 ) \geq \nu_l(b) $$
and so, since $U_n$ is independent of $(X_1,\ldots,X_n,U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1})$ and therefore of $(E_1,\ldots,E_{n-1},X_n)$,
\begin{align*}
& \ P(E_n | 1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1) \\
=& \ P(X_n=b \ \text{ and } \ U_np_n(1_{E_1},\ldots,1_{E_{n-1}}) \leq \nu_l(b) | 1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1) \\
=& \ P(X_n=b \ \text{ and } \ U_np_n(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) \leq \nu_l(b) | 1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1) \\
=& \ P(X_n=b | 1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1) P(U_np_n(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n) \leq \nu_l(b)) \\
=& \ p_n(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)\tfrac{\nu_l(b)}{p_n(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)} \\
=& \ \nu_l(b).
\end{align*}
Since this holds for every $(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_{n-1})$ with $P(1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1) > 0$, it follows that $E_n$ is independent of $(E_1,\ldots,E_{n-1})$ with $P(E_n)=\nu_l(b)$.

Comment: Hopefully the proof is clearer now!

Comment: @TEX (1) is by integrating the inequality $P(X_n=b|X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1}) \geq \nu_l(b)$ over sets of the form $\{1_{E_i}=\alpha_i \ \forall \, 1 \leq i \leq n-1\}$, as these sets are measurable with respect to $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1},U_1,\ldots,U_{n-1})$. (2) uses the strong law of large numbers applied to $(1_{E_n})$ together with the fact that $1_{\{X_n=b\}} \geq 1_{E_n}$ for all $n$ (since $E_n \subset \{X_n=b\}$). I suggest you have an in-person discussion with a probability professor at your university if you need further clarifications on these points :)